# How to set focus to textbox on Onchange event of dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onchange, setfocus

I have textbox whose visibility is controlled by value selected in telerik dropdown. Say if value selected is yes then textbox is visible else it hides. Now when value in dropdown set to Yes i am not able to set focus to that textbox. Only on pressing 'Tab' key focus moves over there but not as soon as textbox appears. I have tried this code:

```
function OnDropDownChange(e){
if ($(this).val() === "Y") {

        $("#txtID").show();
        $("#txtID").focus();            
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#txtID").show(400, function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanx. It did worked. But now issue is that when dropdown value is changed using keyboard, it doesn't show textbox. On tab it shows textbox. Tried to write keyup event on dropdown but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it can be work:

```
$('#txtID').show('slow', function() {
 $(this).focus();
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/show/)